# How do I declare an instance of one of my Rust structs as static?

Tags: struct, static, rust

How do I declare an instance of one of my own structs as static? This sample doesn't compile:

```
static SERVER: Server<'static> = Server::new();

fn main() {
    SERVER.start("127.0.0.1", 23);
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can’t call any non-`const` functions inside a global. Often you will be able to do something like struct literals, though privacy rules may prevent you from doing this, where there are private fields and you’re not defining it in the same module.

So if you have something like this:

```
struct Server<'a> {
    foo: &'a str,
    bar: uint,
}
```

You can write this:

```
const SERVER: Server<'static> = Server {
    foo: "yay!",
    bar: 0,
};
```

… but that’s the best you’ll get in a true `static` or `const` declaration. There are, however, workarounds for achieving this sort of thing, such as [lazy-static](https://github.com/Kimundi/lazy-static.rs), in which your `Server::new()` *is* completely legitimate.